# Internal Server Error 500 on Axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, axios, internals

I have api running at http://localhost:81/log_api.php, then I have React app on the same computer running at http://localhost:3000. Below is the codes for React app :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Logging extends Component {

   state={
       pl_log:[]
     }

     async componentDidMount(){
        await axios.get("http://localhost:81/log_api.php")
         .then(response=>this.setState(
             {
               pl_log: response.data

             } ))

        console.log(this.state)       
     }


   render(){
       return(
           <div>
               Logging
           </div>
       )
   }
  }

  export default Logging;
```

Console.log shows some errors :
[image]

I have also directly visited http://localhost:81/log_api.php , no problem at all. It shows the JSON data on the browser. The problem only occurs when I use axios in React.

filename : log_api.php

```
<?php



$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "root", "masterdb");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = $link -> query("SELECT * FROM pl_log");
$result=array();

while ($data = $sql -> fetch_assoc()){
    $result[]=$data;
}
echo json_encode($result);


mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Network screenshot :
[image]

Comment: Is your PHP server CORS ready?

Comment: I have added CORS extension on Chrome.

Comment: I run MAMP server on my local computer.

Comment: 500 Error number means the server has a general problem. 503 indicates a runtime error.

Comment: can you check the network tab and take a screenshot of the error

Comment: It's not a CORS issue, that would fail with a different error. A 500 error indicates something went wrong in your PHP script. In the network inspector of your browser, you should still be able to access the response your API sent. Assuming you have [error reporting enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/1941241), that may tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: You are mixing mysql apis. `mysql_close()` cannot be used with a `mysqli` connection. I'd venture a guess that it fails in the browser as well, but you don't see it since it's the very last thing PHP tries to do. If you look at the network tab when you directly request it, does it also show a 500 error (despite showing the correct JSON)?

Answer (score 0):

You may try with Ip address 
`http://127.0.0.1`

Hope it will work for you

Comment: it is clearly thrown a server error, please check your PHP code and CORS